# SQL query number of parent

Tags: sql, mysql, hierarchical-data

I have a table in my database called `type`

```
ID  Name     ParentID
---------------------
1   name1    0
2   name2    0
3   name3    1
4   name4    2
5   name1    1
```

I need to know how many parent (descendants) each type has

### ID  -------- descendants

```
ID-> 1   (have no parent)
ID-> 3   (have 1 parent (ID->1))
ID-> 5   (have two parent ((ID->3(ID->1))))
```

How can I write an optimized sql statement to do this using MySQL?

Comment: i would suggest adding a 'level' column, and when inserting a row/assigning a parent, set it to the parent level + 1.  The top level (no parents) will have level 1.

Comment: See: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

MySQL unfortunately doesn't support recursive CTE's.  But if the number of parents is limited, you can implement this using joins:

```
select p.id
,      case 
           <... more whens here ...>
           when c3.id is not null then 3
           when c2.id is not null then 2
           when c1.id is not null then 1
           else 0
       end as NumberOfChildren
from yourtable p
left join yourtable c1 on c1.parentid = p.id
left join yourtable c2 on c2.parentid = c1.id
left join yourtable c3 on c3.parentid = c2.id
<... more joins here ...>
group by p.id
```

Comment: maybe i don'y descripe my problem well 
but i meant to get descendants for a parent

Answer (score 0):

Also you could implement function to compute level
Sort of:

```
create function get_level(_id int) returns int
begin
  declare _level int default -1;
  repeat
    set _level = _level + 1;

    select parent_id
    into _id
    from your_table
    where id = _id; 
  until _id is null
  end repeat;
  return _level;  
end
```

Usage:

```
select id, get_level(id)  
from your_table
```

I do not test a code.
That approach is not effective. In most cases advice to store and compute level on insert/update is better.

Comment: i can't find the answer till now

Comment: Don't think MySQL supports functions?

Comment: Yes, mySQL 5.x supports functions.      
What is your version?      
Please try my code, I hope it helps.